# Make Ionic 1 toggle switch look like the iOS one on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

I'm working on an Ionic 1 project with a toggle switch in it. You know:

`<ion-toggle>hello</ion-toggle>`

It looks different on Android to iOS, and I prefer the iOS one. I know that in Ionic 2, I can do:

`<ion-toggle mode="ios">hello</ion-toggle>`

But this is an Ionic 1 project and I don't want to convert it to Ionic 2 just for this. Am I out of luck?

Comment: Creating a custom component or overwrite the css to make it to look like a ios toggle even if it just a checkbox element.

Comment: I'd say, don't try to replicate the look and feel of another OS. The user never expects that.

Comment: Is it useful? : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxONGy?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using below two options:

1. `$ionicConfigProvider`. You can configure lots of stuff(style/value/animation etc) using this. Use it inside `myApp.config()`.

**Usage**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('reallyCoolApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(5);

  // note that you can also chain configs
  $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('Go Back').icon('ion-chevron-left');
});
```

**Your requirement**:
You need to style the toggle item using ``

> **form.toggle(value)** Toggle item style. Android defaults to `small` and
>   iOS defaults to `large`.

Use below if you want to set style for all the toggles in your project:
`$ionicConfigProvider.form.toggle('large');`

Checkout the `form.toggle` at this link :

[$ionicConfigProvider](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/)

2. using CSS class:
   Add `class="toggle-large"` to `ion-toggle` like below to style specific toggle:

`<ion-toggle class="toggle-large">hello</ion-toggle>`

**Working example code:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxONGy?editors=101

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I sat down at my desk today with a heavy heart, ready to start trying to copy chunks of iOS CSS all over the place with !important stuck to them and instead the whole thing is working exactly how I wanted in two minutes. Will award bounty as soon as I can.

Comment: @ChrisRae You are welcome. I am happy that I could help you.